# Returning a Model to View from Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model, server-error

I am new to ASP.NET MVC Web Applications.

I am getting the following Error when I try to access: 
http://localhost:1160/View/ViewMovies

ViewMovies is an Action that returns a Model to View. Likewise, I have a similar Action named ViewCustomers, which is also giving me the same error.

**Error**
[image]

**ViewController.cs**

```
 public class ViewController : Controller
{
    // GET: View
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    private MovieCustomerViewModel model = new MovieCustomerViewModel();
    public ActionResult ViewMovies()
    {
        model.movies = new List<Movie> {
            new Movie{id=1,name="Shrek"},
            new Movie{id=1,name="Wall-e"}
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult ViewCustomers()
    {
        model.customers = new List<Customer> {
            new Customer{id=1,name="Junaid"},
            new Customer{id=1,name="Zohaib"}
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

I have added a view folder named Movie_Customer:

[image]

It has two separate .cshtml files named, Customers.cshtml and Movies.cshtml

**Customers.cshtml**

```
@model Ex1.ViewModels.MovieCustomerViewModel


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customers";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Customers</h2>


<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" />
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
</tr>

@{
    foreach (var v in Model.customers)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>v.id</td>
            <td>v.name</td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

**Movies.cshtml**

```
@model Ex1.ViewModels.MovieCustomerViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Movies";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Movies</h2>


<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" />
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
</tr>

@{
    foreach (var v in Model.movies)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>v.id</td>
            <td>v.name</td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

I am doing exactly what's done here: http://techfunda.com/howto/240/return-model-to-view-from-action-method

What am I doing wrong?
How do I remove these errors? 
What should I must know about handling Views or View Models?

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: So the error message is self explanatory. As per the convention, you view files should located in one of those directories and the view name should match the action method name. But you can override the convention by explicitly passing a view path If you want. Make sure your views are strongly typed to the same type as the data you are returning/passing from the action method to the view.

Comment: Your controller should probably be named `MovieCustomerController` and your view folder should be `Views/MovieCustomer`. Then you can specify the view name in your return value, e.g. `return View("Customers", model)`.

Comment: @Shyju I have changed the names and it works. Thanks. But I am confused about it. What If my Controller also contains a couple of more actions (with different names obviously) which are to use the same .cshtml view files but there names are different than the .cshtml files?

Comment: You can explicitly pass a view `return View("~/Views/Customer/index.cshtml`, listOdCustomers)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller is named `ViewController` and by convention  the framework will check the `~Views/<ControllerNamePrefix>/` directory and `Views/Shared/` directory for a view file matching the name that youre requesting (here you're requesting `ViewCustomers` and `ViewMovies` since you are using `return View(model)` the framework will look for a view with a name that matches the action. If you want to specify the name of the view then use `return View("ViewName", model)`)

To resolve your error, you can rename your view to `ViewCustomers.cshtml` and `ViewMovies.cshtml` and put those files in a new directory: location `/Views/View/`.

Personally, I'd recommend renaming your controller as well since `ViewController` doesn't really say anything about what the controller should be responsible for. In MVC applications, most all controllers will be returning views.

In summary:

- You're requesting views named `ViewCustomers.cshtml` and `ViewMovies.cshtml` which don't exist in any folder.
- Your views are not located in the write
  subdirectory in the `Views` folder for the framework to be able to find
  them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused because when trying to return a view from controller you have to take the literal name and place it in the return overflow as

```
return View("Customer",model)
```

Or when constructing a controller you might want right click the name of the controller and select the option "Create view" for the selected controller, this would automatically bind those two together.

Views don't share the same naming convention as controllers